# Dynamically send a number of params to a method depending if parameters are nil or not

Tags: ruby

I want to avoid doing this:

```
if a
     some_method(a, b)
else
     some_method(b)
end
```

**some_method** is a function that accepts two parameters, first is a namespace, if not provided then it just accepts the method (b).

**Notes:**

- I can't send 'a' with an empty string or nil.
- I can't modify **some_method**.

Is there a way to do this in **one single line**?

Comment: Why you can't modify **some_method** isn't this what ruby was all about?  :)

Comment: Of course, but this is just an example of a SOAP API I'm using, I have some methods which I don't have access to the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you have a method which allows a variable number of arguments. You could do it like this:

```
args = [a,b]
some_method(*(args.compact))
```

What this does: the compact removes nils from a list. Then the * ( splat operator ), "expands" the array elements into the proper positions.

Comment: The parens around `args.compact` aren't necessary. The splat operator binds less strongly than a message send.

Comment: I prefer to be explicit wherever possible :)

Comment: +1 for mind reading. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30965/can-we-have-a-mind-reading-badge  The op never mentioned the method had varargs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way may be...

```
args = a ? [a, b] : [b]
some_method(*args)
```

So for the single line:

```
some_method(*(a ? [a, b] : [b]))
```

But is that really worth it? ^^

Happy coding.

Comment: Nice! in fact looks like the solution I chose but instead of using compact, still it's useful for me, thanks!